# UIImage from JSon

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage

i want to ask again about uiimage from json. here's my json

```
   - image {
        original: "http://someurl/B777_Tail.jpg",
         thumbnail: "http://someurl/thumbnail/B777_Tail.jpg"
     },
```

nah, i have try to get this with this method on UItableviewcell

```
NSString *path=[[[json objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"image"]objectForKey:@"thumbnail"];
    NSLog(@"%@",path);


    UIImage *theImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];
    cell.imageView.image = theImage;
```

is any wrong in my code? because it not showing on UItableviewCell;

Comment: well...you have some URLs there. `imageWithContentsOfFile` will load ...from a file. You can try using AsyncImageView . Search it on gitHub.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first you're loading image in wrong way. The simpliest loading code will be like

```
NSData* imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString: path]];
UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithData: imageData];
```

If your path is extracted correctly, you'll see the image.